# Узнать размер таблицы Clickhouse. Engine Log

Tags: clickhouse

Подскажите, как я могу узнать, сколько весит таблица с движком `log` на `clickhouse`?

Нашел способ с system.parts, но он работает только для таблиц с `engine == 'MergeTree'`

```sql
SELECT table,
    formatReadableSize(sum(bytes)) as size,
    FROM system.parts
    WHERE active
GROUP BY table
```

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас нет такой встроенной возможности (см. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/9001), нужно это сделать вручную.

Это перевод моего ответа на вопрос [Enable system.columns for Log Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046828/303298):

1. Определим местоположение файлов таблицы на диске

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.tables
WHERE name = '{table name}'
FORMAT Vertical

/* Result:
Row 1:
──────
..
data_paths:                 ['/var/lib/clickhouse/data/test/log_engine_001/']
..
*/
```

2. используем системную функцию, чтобы оценить размер таблицы

```bsh
sudo ls -lsh /var/lib/clickhouse/data/test/log_engine_001

# Result:
# total 88K
# 4.0K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse  64 Feb  3 20:28 __marks.mrk
#  40K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse 40K Feb  3 20:28 id.bin
#  40K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse 40K Feb  3 20:28 name.bin
# 4.0K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse 100 Feb  3 20:28 sizes.json
```